# what is the collectionView form of indexPathForSelectedRow?

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, nsindexpath

I'm attempting to create a variable "indexx" that will be segued to my next tableController. indexx will hold the indexPath of the selected cell from my collectionView, however, I am unsure which property to use. I am vastly more familiar with tableController properties so I'm having difficulty finding a successful solution to this piece of code. Would you happen to know my error?

As a quick note - foodcv is my collectionView and numberr is the variable in the second destination controller.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destViewController = segue.destination as? foodtable {
        let indexx = self.foodcv.indexPath(for: foodcell)
        destViewController.numberr = indexx
    }
}


let numberr : IndexPath = []
```

Comment: [`collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/indexPathsForSelectedItems)

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/indexPathsForSelectedItems

Comment: is there a indexpathforselecteditem - as in singular?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UICollectionView/allowsMultipleSelection

Comment: @jonpeter no there is not but `allowsMultipleSelection=false` guarantees `collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems()` returning either 1 or 0 elements so you can check like: `if let selectedPath = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems().first { ...`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's too late, but here you go:

**Swift 4**

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destViewController = segue.destination as? foodtable {
        let indexPaths : NSArray = foodcv.indexPathsForSelectedItems! as NSArray
        let indexx : IndexPath = indexPaths[0] as! IndexPath
        destViewController.numberr = indexx[selectedindexPath.row]
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this modified implementation,

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destViewController = segue.destination as? foodtable {
        let indexx = self.foodcv.indexPathForCell(sender as! UICollectionViewCell)
        destViewController.numberr = indexx
    }
}
```